# Is Super Saiyan Rosé Goku Black's version of the Super Saiyan Blue or his version of the original (golden) Super Saiyan?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

According to the Dragon Ball Wikia for [Super Saiyan Rosé](https://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_Ros%C3%A9),

> Akira Toriyama's notes for the form seem to indicate that this state is simply the Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan (blue) state with pink hair.

but according to [Super Saiyan Rosé is the Super Saiyan version of Goku](https://www.dragonballnoticias.com/el-super-saiyajin-rose-es-la-version-super-saiyajin-de-black-goku) in Spanish, there is a Japanese magazine which says,

> Super Saiyan Rosé is the Super Saiyajin (golden) version of Black Goku

None of the sources is an official source. Any other info states which version is the equivalent of Super Saiyan Rosé, Super Saiyan Blue, or Super Saiyan (golden)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given recently in manga 20 and it's Blue. Rose is Black's version of the Super Saiyan Blue.

Source (Spanish only): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sJzIM8uvcQ

Answer (score 0):

In the anime version, it **isn't** stated that Super Saiyan Rose is another version of Super Saiyan Blue. But in the **guides**, it is stated that it is Goku Black's version of Super Saiyan 1.

Answer (score 0):

Simple question with a simple answer:

- Manga = Goku Black's version of Super Saiyan Blue
- Anime = Goku Black's version of Super Saiyan